# Including a book extract in my blog

Tags: legal, blog

Can I include an extract of another persons book in my blog with references?

If so, are there any restrictions that I must follow?

Comment: The restriction is copyright law. Making a copy of another person's work is a violation of their copyright, except as allowed by copyright law.

Comment: and copyright law isn't always US copyright law...

Answer (score 2):

This depends a lot on the context and scope. If you simply post excerpts from a copyrighted work without any commentary, criticism, or analysis, you're pushing your luck (**even** if you include attribution). If, on the other hand, you need to include some excerpts as a part of an article of your own that, for instance, analyzes the work in question (or compares it to others), this is generally acceptable, within reason (= you can post a paragraph or two, but not any extensive blocks of text).

Comment: I need to include excerpts from a popular and well known novel in an online course that I am creating, for analysis purposes. You're answer indicates that I should be fine, but I was wondering if you could provide me with a link or two to back it up.

Comment: http://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/fair-use/what-is-fair-use/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, so long as it meets the criteria for "fair use." For more background, I recommend reading the following Wikipedia topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use